# How to Fix the width attribute in cross browser environment

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please see the JS link here

http://trac.openwebanalytics.com/browser/trunk/modules/base/js/includes/jquery/jquery.ui.selectmenu.js?rev=1436

```
(function($) {

    $.widget("ui.selectmenu", {
            getter: "value",
            version: "1.8",
            eventPrefix: "selectmenu",
            options: {
                    transferClasses: true,
                    typeAhead: "sequential",
                    style: 'dropdown',
                    positionOptions: {
                            my: "left top",
                            at: "left bottom",
                            offset: null
                    },
                    width: null,
                    menuWidth: null,
                    handleWidth: 26,
                    maxHeight: null,
                    icons: null,
                    format: null,
                    bgImage: function() {},
                    wrapperElement: ""
            },
```

This width attribute defined below is being browser specific .
For  instance this width  value  is being browser specific , for example for Crome it is 97px , IE 8 it  is  67px 
So as a result it is not looking good inside IE .
Please tell me how can we fix it ??

Comment: Show us an example of what you're talking about, not just the widget's source code.

Comment: This is more than likely a CSS issue. Some more code would be appreciated, or maybe a live link.

Answer (score 0):

As a hack, maybe set the width to be what looks good, depending on which browser the script is running in; you can use this to determine the browser type: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/